# Error in Trace SIP - Timeout of call server

Tags: sip, telephony, phone-call, simultaneous-calls

thank you for your help.

We have an application that generates calls to the customers, around 500 SIP calls simultaneous. Our app is only a customer of the SBC-Call Server. 
When the application start, the first calls are completed, but after that calls, we receive an timeout of the call server (50 seconds), for this reason we send a CANCEL in the signalization, because we do not receive any answer of the call server.

The trace of an call is:

[image: trace]

0.80 We send an INVITE to call server
0.81 The call server returns 100 Trying.
50.79 We send a CANCEL (But 50 seconds later) why we do not receive any message.

What is the problem, the call server does not support the multiple sessions (500 calls)?

Comment: What kind of software is the call server (Asterisk?)?

Comment: Hello, the call server is  Cisco-SIPGateway IOS-15.4.3.M4. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

By sending the `100 Trying`, the server indicates that it received the `INVITE` and it tries to route it. After the `CANCEL`, there is `487`, meaning there was an active `INVITE` transaction. So without knowing what actually happened inside the SIP server, the assumption can be:

- the SIP server had no more resources to route the `INVITE` out
- `INVITE` was sent by the SIP server out, but there was no response from downstream to it

To really be able troubleshoot properly, you need to check the logs/activity of the SIP server and/or watch the SIP traffic on the network after the SIP server.